# mongod facing with file permission on linux mint

Tags: node.js, linux, mongodb

what is the exact file permission for data/db?

why this problem occurs?

2016-10-18T17:19:28.378+0600 E NETWORK  [initandlisten] listen(): bind() failed errno:98 Address already in use for socket: 0.0.0.0:27017

2016-10-18T17:19:28.378+0600 E NETWORK  [initandlisten]   addr already in use
2016-10-18T17:19:28.378+0600 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] Failed to set up sockets during startup.
2016-10-18T17:19:28.378+0600 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 48

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restart your computer and then try again.

Comment: @Md.Samsuzzoha great! Please mark my answer as the accepted answer and vote up (click the V and the up arrow).

Comment: sure :)
@Alon i want to make a conversation with you in that case can i get your mail?